Getting or setting a value when clicking a checkbox in a datagrid view
Im trying to get a value once I click on a checkbox for a custom DataGrid view filled with a SQL query. The idea its to build a list of selected items with the value ID_COMANDA to delete later
Now I dont know why Im getting a null exceptcion error. I tried to set it via data building it just dosent work
This is the funtion that sets data into the data grid
private void ComandasProcesadas(Mesas mesa_seleccionada)
 {


     // Fetch the data
     List<Comanda> comandas_procesadas = Database.GetComandasActivas(mesa_seleccionada.ID_MESA);

     // Set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false
     COMANDAS_PROCESADAS.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
     // Handle the CellPainting event to draw a larger checkbox
     COMANDAS_PROCESADAS.CellPainting += new DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(COMANDAS_PROCESADAS_CellPainting);

    

     COMANDAS_PROCESADAS.CellContentClick += DataGridView_CellContentClick;

    // Add the DataGridView to the form's controls
    // this.Controls.Add(COMANDAS_PROCESADAS);

     // Clear existing rows and set DataSource
     COMANDAS_PROCESADAS.Rows.Clear();
     COMANDAS_PROCESADAS.DataSource = comandas_procesadas;

     
   
 }

This is the SQL query and data binding
while (reader.Read())
{
  
    var comanda = new Comanda
    {
        ID_COMANDA = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID_COMANDA"]),
        NUM_COMANDA = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NUM_COMANDA"]),
        CANTIDAD = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["CANTIDAD"]),
        ITEM = reader["ITEM"].ToString(),
        TOTAL = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["TOTAL"]),
        NOTAS = reader["NOTAS"].ToString(),
        NOMBRE_SALONERO = reader["NOMBRE_SALONERO"].ToString(),
        FECHA = reader["FECHA"].ToString(),
        TIEMPO_COMANDA = CalculateDifference(reader["FECHA"].ToString(), reader["HORA_INICIO"].ToString()),
        IsNote = false // Regular row

       
    };
    Console.WriteLine(comanda.ToString());
    comandas_procesadas.Add(comanda);
}

EDIT
The checkbox is defined using the dataview grid using the build editor
enter image description here
The exception is here
enter image description here
I dont know why Im failing. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance !
Create a list of selected items

I don't see a checkbox in your code.  Where are you getting the error? After you click?  Is the value not being passed correctly to the function?

"it just dosent work". That is not a problem description. You need to explain EXACTLY what you expect and EXACTLY what actually happens. If an exception is thrown, you need to provide the type, the actual error message, where it is thrown and what data is in use at the time. In short, you need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. The more vague you are, the less we're able to help and thus the less likely we are to try.

I already did an edit with more details on the issue

Because the .Value property is null and you can't convert (bool)null. Write instead: var isChecked = (bool)dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;. Also, there's FormattedValue property. See the docs for more.
